# Calling ForEach with an anonymous action

Tags: c#

Compiling this code:

```
           var arr = new[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19 };
           arr.ForEach(x =>
                    {
                          Console.WriteLine(x);
                    });
```

Fails with:

```
error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'action' of 'Array.ForEach<T>(T[], Action<T>)'
```

Why?

Comment: `arr.ToList().ForEach` will work but on array it is static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2(v=vs.110).aspx) is a static method on the `Array` class. It is not, however, an extension method.

The documentation for the method states the following (emphasis mine):

> Performs the specified action on each element of the **specified array**.

It takes two parameters:

1. `T[]` - The one-dimensional, zero-based Array on whose elements the action is to be performed.
2. `Action<T>` - The Action to perform on each element of array.

You need to call it like this:

```
Array.ForEach(arr, x =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
});
```

Comment: But the error message says that such extension method exists.

Comment: @Elena Where? Where does it say that?

Comment: @Elena You can clearly see [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D4bp5M) that `TestClass` has no extension method but generates a similar error.